# Solaris user management: switching to other user account

Tags: solaris

I need to ensure that Solaris always requires user to enter the password when switching to other user accounts.

What file contains the configuration for this? Is it actually possible to implement this e.g. for root user switching to regular user account? Is there any difference between Solaris-10 and Solaris-11 wrt to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**root** can **su** to any user without a password, as to what a non root users can do, and whether they need to provide credentials, check your **sudoers** file e.g.

```
/etc/sudoers
/usr/local/etc/sudoers
```